# Firebase Swift: queryEqualToValue by childKey is not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Has anyone have any luck using the function:

```
.queryEqualToValue(value: AnyObject?, childKey: String?)
```

Two things:

1) The childKey does not seem to allow deep paths, just direct children

2) I can't get it to work at all! Given my structure:

```
"post": {
  "groupName": "hello world"
}
```

If I do a simple:

```
postRef.queryEqualToValue("hello world", childKey: "groupName").observeSingleEvent( ... )
```

It does not return any posts at all. Instead I have to do the roundabout way of:

```
postRef.queryOrderedByChild("groupName").queryEqualToValue("hello world").observeSingleEvent( ... )
```

to get it to work!

**Am I using the above function incorrectly?**

Comment: That last snippet looks correct. The first snippet is always causing people trouble, so I tend to ignore it.

Comment: I can not get the `queryOrderedByChild("").queryEqualToValue("")` to work at all!?

Answer (score 10):

The following is written in the Firebase documentation:

> **queryEqualToValue** Return items equal to the specified key, value, or priority, depending on the order-by method chosen.

[Retrieve Data on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data#filtering_data)

The important part is: ***"depending on the order-by method chosen."***

So make sure, you combine the ***queryEqualToValue***-Method with a ***orderBy***-Method.

For example:

```
    let groupState = "open"

    ref.child("groups").queryOrdered(byChild:"state").queryEqual(toValue:groupState).observe(enventType: .value, with: { snapshot in
        // Returns all groups with state "open"
        for group in snapshot.children {
            print(group)
        }
    })
```

PS: The variant with ***childKey*** is not mentioned in the new Firebase iOS-Guides.

Comment: Is the childKey variant deprecated? It seems to not work

Answer (score 8):

Xcode 7.2.1
Swift 2.1.1
iOS 9.2
OSX 10.10.5

> 2) I can't get it to work at all! Given my structure:
>
> ```
> "post": {
>   "groupName": "hello world"
> }
> ```
>
> If I do a simple:
>
> ```
> postRef.queryEqualToValue("hello world", childKey: "groupName")
> postRef.queryEqualToValue("hello world", childKey: "groupName").observeSingleEvent( ... )
> ```

I can successfully get the query with the following code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dbRef: FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        dbRef.child("post").child("groupName").setValue("hello world")

        let postRef = dbRef.child("post")
        print(postRef)

        let query = postRef.queryEqualToValue("hello world", childKey: "groupName")
        print(query)


    --output:--
    (/post {
        en = groupName;
        ep = "hello world";
        sn = groupName;
        sp = "hello world";
    })
```

> 1) The childKey does not seem to allow deep paths, just direct
>   children

I'm not seeing that. If I change my code to:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dbRef: FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        dbRef.child("post").child("groupName").child("userId").setValue("hello world")

        let postRef = dbRef.child("post")
        print(postRef)

        let query = postRef.queryEqualToValue("hello world", childKey: "userId")
        print(query)
```

I get the following output:

```
(/post {
    en = userId;
    ep = "hello world";
    sn = userId;
    sp = "hello world";
})
```

However, I cannot get the observers to work--they certainly don't work like the docs say they do.

I delete all my data on Firebase before I run the app.

**Edit**:  Okay, I think I know what's going on with my observers.  According to the [Retrieve Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data#listen_for_events) section:

> Firebase data is retrieved by attaching an asynchronous listener to a
>   <strike>FIRDatabase reference</strike> FIRDatabaseReference. The listener is triggered once for the initial
>   state of the data and again anytime the data changes.

When I try observing a query, the snapshot in the callback doesn't have any data in it.  On the other hand, when I observe a `FirDatabaseReference` the observer works (somewhat) like I expect.

For example, if I observe a FIRDatabaseReference like this:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dbRef: FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        dbRef.child("post").child("groupName").child("userId").setValue("hello world")

        let postRef = dbRef.child("post")
        postRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            print(snapshot)
        })

        sleep(1) //Allow the observer (in another thread) to execute before the following line:
        dbRef.child("post").child("groupName").child("userId").setValue("goodbye Mars")


    }
```

then the snapshot in the callback has data in it, and I get this output:

```
Snap (post) {
    groupName =     {
        userId = "hello world";
    };
}
Snap (post) {
    groupName =     {
        userId = "goodbye Mars";
    };
}
```

But if I observe a FIRDatabaseQuery:

```
let postRef = dbRef.child("post")
let query = postRef.queryEqualToValue("hello world", childKey: "userID")

query.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
    print(snapshot)
})
```

then the output is:

```
Snap (post) <null>
```